# clean installation on old laptop

Tags: laptop

I have an old laptop Dell Inspiron 9400 running Windows Vista. Can I format it and do a clean install of Ubuntu 16.04 from a flash drive or should I  burn it on a DVD and do so?

Also, where can I get an installation DVD for the above, in Indianapolis?

Comment: if your laptop will boot from USB, then that will be faster than using a DVD. Download the disc image from http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop and follow the installation guide http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-ubuntu-desktop